# What happen when we drop table & package in oracle?

Tags: oracle

I am created a new table, wrote package & gave execute access to one user for this package. Is it necessary to create rollback script for these tasks?

- When the table is dropped the trigger will  be dropped. AM i right?
- When the package is dropped the execute rights will automatically get
  dropped. AM i right?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, a trigger must always be for a table or view - so if you drop the table (or view, as the case may be), all triggers on that object will be automatically dropped as well.*
2. Yes, privileges are always on an object - if you drop the object (e.g. a package), all privileges on that object will be lost as well.

If you subsequently `CREATE` a new object with the same name, the old triggers and privileges will not magically reappear - you would have to add them manually.

Alternatively, if you `CREATE OR REPLACE` a package, the privileges on the original package will remain. Similarly, if you `ALTER` a table, the triggers will not be affected.

** In Oracle 11g, by default a dropped table gets moved to the Recycle Bin. If the table had any triggers, they get moved to the Recycle Bin as well.*

Comment: If you drop a package - do all sprocs in the package get dropped too? Or just the package itself, while preserving the sprocs in the body?

Comment: @bleepzter, don't confuse stored procs with package procs. If you drop a package, all its contents are dropped (including any procedures defined within it). A stored procedure, on the other hand, is a separate schema object in its own right and needs to be dropped separately.